# In Photoshop CC 2018 What is this grey background behind Artboards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

[image]

Why there is a grey background appearing behind artboards in Photoshop CC 2018, it extends to the number of artboards, it started appearing in Photoshop CC 2018.

Comment: Not seeing it on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott, my configuration - i7 (6700K), Ram: 16Gb, OS: Win10

Comment: Kind of irrelevant. Tech support questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Not exactly a support question may be a kind new functionality added in the new version, just looking forward to getting rid of it.

Comment: The things is.. *why* an application does what it does is not in the realm of graphic design knowledge most of the time. You kind of need to ask Adobe *why* something is the way it is.

Comment: I think I can kind of see why it is there, although I haven't upgraded to 2018 yet.  You are merely hiding the artboards - the grey background appears to be there to show you where they are located. Try deleting the artboards instead.